# apache redirecting www to subdomain

Tags: node.js, apache, redirect

I got a server which will contains many application and one presentation page (served by Apache).

www subdomain will be my presentation page and subdomain will be apps.

At the moment, I got only one app which is written in NodeJs (port 4000 for example).

I want to redirect traffic from xxx.mydomain.com to localhost:4000, which is working with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName xxx.mydomain.com:443

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /root/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/privatekey.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert.ca-bundle

<Location />
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:4000/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that apache is redirecting www.mydomain.com to xxx.mydomain.com automatically and I got certificate error because xxx.domain.com is certified for this subdomain and not www.mydomain.com.

I put this config in the same file as the xxx.domain.com vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:433>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /root/wwwcert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/wwwkey.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /root/wwwcert.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

What should I do ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to enter juste your **ServerName**, not port after the FQDN ?

```
ServerName www.mydomain.com
```

And no

```
ServerName www.mydomain.com:443
```